# Is there a way to get Facebook public page past events using graph API?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I want to get past events for a public facebook page (of an organization that i am working for) to integrate with their wordpress website (which i am working on)

What is the solution here?

I cannot seem to be able to use any plugins or even the facebook graph API to be able to accomplish this. (checked the graph api explorer, and it returns no data)

on the documentation it says that the events is a restricted edge
 but still they have :

GET /v3.3/{page-id}/events HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

Does this not work?

Even if I use facebook's ugly page plugin, i cannot get page PAST events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events:

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

There is currently no way for normal 3rd-party apps to get page events *at all*.

Comment: So currently..there is now way to accomplish this..no wodpress plugin..no graph api..
are there like services that parse the facebook page?

Comment: There are probably services like that - but scraping Facebook pages is against their ToS to begin with – so if you need one of those, you should go research one yourself, recommending such services does not really fit here.

Comment: is the edge still restricted if i'm page admin? wanted to avoid this case because i did not want to complicated things with the social media officers and red tape etc

Comment: Yes; this has nothing to do with which role a specific user might have on a page.